How big should be the nail groove on a snap fit lid?
I am not aware if this site is strictly only for software UX design and not for physical products. Please excuse me if it's not.
On most snap fit enclosures there is usually a groove or indent into which you can put your finger to lift up the lid and open it. Without this the lid of the enclosure would be difficult to open.
I am designing a 3D printed enclosure which has snap fits. How big is it usually accepted for this nail groove to be for comfortable user experience?
Although this question might seem like I'm dumb and can't just make it big enough for a normal person's nails, I want some facts on how big it's accepted for the nail groove to be for an optimal user experience.

I have currently made it a rectangle with the top two corners curved. Dimensions are 20mm long, 2.5mm tall, and 1mm deep.

Maybe a “thumb” question but certainly not a dumb question. And yes, questions about physical design are allowed and have been asked before.

Anthropometric hand dimensions differ from region to region across the globe. You need to find data for the population you have in mind. Then there will be questions like - age group (older people may not be very nimble), with/without gloves. I believe the thumb size of 95 percentile should give you the answer.
